# asyncio - How can coroutines be used in signal handlers?

Tags: python, signals, coroutine, python-asyncio

I am developing an application that uses asyncio from python3.4 for networking. When this application shuts down cleanly, a node needs to "disconnect" from the hub. This disconnect is an active process that requires a network connection so the loop needs to wait for this to complete before shutting down.

My issue is that using a coroutine as a signal handler will result in the application not shutting down. Please consider the following example:

```
import asyncio
import functools
import os
import signal

@asyncio.coroutine
def ask_exit(signame):
    print("got signal %s: exit" % signame)
    yield from asyncio.sleep(10.0)
    loop.stop()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
for signame in ('SIGINT', 'SIGTERM'):
    loop.add_signal_handler(getattr(signal, signame),
                                        functools.partial(ask_exit, signame))

print("Event loop running forever, press CTRL+c to interrupt.")
print("pid %s: send SIGINT or SIGTERM to exit." % os.getpid())
loop.run_forever()
```

If you run this example and then press Ctrl+C, nothing will happen.
The question is, how do I make this behavior happen with siganls and coroutines?

Comment: I have found an answer to this on the python-tulip list: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/python-tulip/Jce-VVXJZvk/o-g74rtuIHkJ

Comment: if you think you found the solution (schedule the coroutine on signal using `asyncio.async` instead of calling it as a signal handler directly); you could [post it as your own answer and accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) so that others could see that the question is answered. Unrelated: you might be insulting some volunteers on this site by suggesting that the motive for them to help you is fictional internet points.

Answer (score 22):

Syntax for python >=3.5

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
for signame in ('SIGINT', 'SIGTERM'):
    loop.add_signal_handler(getattr(signal, signame),
                            lambda: asyncio.ensure_future(ask_exit(signame)))
```

Comment: This does not work as expected. Both lambdas capture `signame` loop variable by reference and both lambdas will get invoked as if `SIGTERM` were sent (`ask_exit('SIGTERM')` is invoked). Writing for each signal line: `loop.add_signal_handler(signal.SIGINT, lambda: asyncio.ensure_future(ask_exit('SIGINT')))` is the easiest solution

Comment: It works. Just an advice Inside `ask_exit` you could **stop the loop but couldn't close it**

Answer (score 15):

Syntax for python >=3.7

```
import asyncio
import signal

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()


async def ask_exit(signame):
    print("got signal %s: exit" % signame)
    await asyncio.sleep(10.0)  # simulate some async clean-up
    loop.stop()

for signame in ('SIGINT', 'SIGTERM'):
    loop.add_signal_handler(getattr(signal, signame),
                            lambda signame=signame: asyncio.create_task(ask_exit(signame)))

# ...do stuff, create more tasks, etc...

loop.run_forever()
```

### Note

This is basically same as [@svs's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42151829/2362553) with two differences:

1. Usage of the more recent Python 3.7+ method `asyncio.create_task` which is "more readable" than `asyncio.ensure_future`.
2. Binding `signame` immediately to the lambda function avoids the problem of [late binding](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures) leading to the expected-unexpected™ behavior referred to in the [comment by @R2RT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23313720/asyncio-how-can-coroutines-be-used-in-signal-handlers#comment99234615_42151829). This was shamelessly copied from [Lynn Root's blog post: Graceful Shutdowns with asyncio](https://www.roguelynn.com/words/asyncio-graceful-shutdowns/) (read the whole [series](https://www.roguelynn.com/words/asyncio-we-did-it-wrong/) to learn more about asyncio's beautiful goriness).

Comment: the problem is that nothing awaits ask_exit() coro, nothing is keeping the process alive to acutally execute the code in ask_exit() to completion, unlease it's like in nodejs where a dangaling promise keeps the process alive (didn't find any thing that states that this is the case in python)

Comment: @eranotzap I have amended the code example to be complete. `create_task` will await the `ask_exit`, as long as the event loop is running.

Comment: Although "await" is not quite correct I guess. A task is created and will run on the event loop asynchronously until it is completed. https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.create_task

Answer (score 5):

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
for signame in ('SIGINT', 'SIGTERM'):
    loop.add_signal_handler(getattr(signal, signame),
                            asyncio.async, ask_exit(signame))
```

That way the signal causes your ask_exit to get scheduled in a task.

Comment: This is invalid syntax in python 3.5.1.

Comment: ask_exit was never awaited exception in python 3.6.4

Answer (score 4):

python3.8

- 1st attempt: used `async def handler_shutdown`, and wrapped it in  `loop.create_task()` when passing to `add_signal_handler()`
- 2nd attempt: don't use async for `def handler_shutdown()`.
- 3rd attempt: wrap handler_shutdown and param in `functools.partial()`

## e.g.

```
import asyncio
import functools
def handler_shutdown(signal, loop, tasks, http_runner, ):
    ...
    ...
def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    for signame in ('SIGINT', 'SIGTERM', 'SIGQUIT'):
                print(f"add signal handler {signame} ...")
                loop.add_signal_handler(
                    getattr(signal, signame),
                    functools.partial(handler_shutdown,
                            signal=signame, loop=loop, tasks=tasks,
                            http_runner=http_runner
                            )
                    )
```

- The main issue i had was error

  `raise TypeError("coroutines cannot be used "`
- solved it by wrapping the routine in loop.create_task()
- then solved it by removing async form signal handler function
- for named param to handler also use functools.partial